# how to build a database in coordination with python 3.4 and have a visual interface for DB mangement?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, python-3.4

I am completely new to python and I want to start working with database in python. I am using **winPython** **version 3.4**. I am using **pymysql** module.
 At very beginning of the project, I had used the code below and faced the error.
import  pymysql as sql
db = sql.connect('localhost','root','','test.db')
Error ==> No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
I guess the reason is because I have made no database. **Actually I don’t know how.**
**where** do I have to **build** the **database**?
 Do I have to **install a sql server** and **build a data base** there?
 If so what is the best **match** for **winpython 3.4**?
  How can I have **graphical interface** to my **DB management** to be able to build tables , insert rows or other things?
*thank you for helping me to start.*

Comment: is this about mysql or sql-server? sql-server means Microsoft SQL Server. please use tags properly

Comment: what I meant by sql server is actually any sql database(like : mysql,sqlite3,sql server or any of them)

Comment: You need to follow the meaning of the tags in forum. Thanks.